# FileSystemRights: List-only folders

Tags: c#, file-permissions

I have a folder with some heavy restrictions on it. For one user, this person can see if a file exists, but cannot copy the file out, open the file, etc. The ONLY thing they can do is to see if the file exists.

When I look at the top-level, I see List folder contents is checked. That's the ONLY permission they are allowed to have.

[image]

Now, when use C# to pull the rights, I see that SEVERAL items are set, not just one. And when I look deeper into the rights, I see that at this lower level, the corresponding items are checked.

[image]

When I get the rights to this folder, it shows that the folder has "READ" access because the low-level flag for read is set. HOWEVER, I've tested with this user's account. They most certainly do not have read access.

If I re-create a new folder and set the rights as listed here, the user can then copy files out of the new folder, which they should NOT be able to do.

I don't understand the Windows security model.

How can I verify that the user has LIST access, but not READ access? What would I query for, specifically? NOTE: Querying for "List Folder/Read Data" but not "Read Permissions" does NOT work, as you can see below. Both of those are apparently set by the higher-level "List Folder Contents" option.

***UPDATE:***

I'm including the code snip I use to pull the information. Maybe that will help define what I'm looking for.

```
    internal void GroupsFromPath(string pth, bool IncludeInherited)
    {
        DirectorySecurity ds;
        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(pth);
            ds = di.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Access);
        }
        catch
        {
            return ret;
        }

        AuthorizationRuleCollection acl = ds.GetAccessRules(true, 
                IncludeInherited, typeof(NTAccount));

        foreach (FileSystemAccessRule ace in acl)
        {
            bool L = CheckRights(ace, FileSystemRights.Traverse |
                FileSystemRights.ListDirectory);

            bool R = CheckRights(ace, FileSystemRights.Read);
            bool W = CheckRights(ace, FileSystemRights.Modify);

            DO_MAGIC(pth, L, R, W);
        }
    }

    private bool CheckRights(FileSystemAccessRule ACE, 
            FileSystemRights fileSystemRights)
    {
        bool r = ((ACE.FileSystemRights & fileSystemRights) == fileSystemRights) 
            && (ACE.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow);

        return r;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For LIST access you have to make sure that the permissions only apply to **"This folder and subfolders"** (see your screenshot).

The `FileSystemAccessRule`'s `InheritanceFlags` property must be set to `InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit` and the `PropagationFlags` property must be set to `PropagationFlags.None`.

For a complete list (InheritanceFlags/PropagationFlags) see the blog of [Damir Dobric](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2007/06/18/directory-security-and-access-rules.aspx).

**BEGIN EDIT**

To check whether or not a given `FileSystemAccessRule` realizes **"List Folder Content Only"** permissions
you can use the following method (using the `InheritanceFlags` and `PropagationFlags` properties):

```
private static bool CheckListFolderContentOnly(FileSystemAccessRule ace)
{
  if (ace.PropagationFlags == PropagationFlags.None &&
      ace.InheritanceFlags == InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit &&
      ace.FileSystemRights == (FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute | FileSystemRights.Synchronize))
  {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

**END EDIT**

Hope, this helps.

Comment: I'm not trying to CHANGE the value. I'm trying to fetch the value that is already in the ACE. I don't see how your statement applies in this situation.

Comment: @Jerry: I've updated my answer. You can use the PropagationFlags and InheritanceFlags to check for "List Folder Content Only" permissions.

Comment: This, to be honest, makes no sense to me, but it DOES return the right value. When I use the same pattern to also check for READ and WRITE, it does return the appropriate true/false values. THANK YOU!!

Comment: How will this behave if the folder is shared and read permissions are there ?